# Disabling error underlining with red in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, gcc, qt-creator

Qt creator uses it's own code analyzer to underline errors in cpp code. But when I use gcc types Qt creator treats `unsigned __int128 mask = 1;` as an error and underlines this line and many subsequent lines. So how to disable error underlining or make Creator validate this declaration properly?

Answer (score 1):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Font&Colors: find and chek the "Error" at the "Color Scheme". Click "Copy", "Ok". Select No underline at the Underline section.

Comment: Your solution makes all error underlines invisible. But this is not what I asked about, because I would like to see "valid" syntax errors underlined.